# Multiple regular expression matching

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm a little lost on the best approach for filtering data (shown below) using multiple criteria.

As an example, `MyServer2` and `Sat 18:00` would result in `MyServer2` and `04-23-16 1800` that I can output into two text files.

```
"Server","MaintenanceWindow","Ping","LastReboot"
"MyServer1","NoDeadline","Alive","4/8/2016 2:44:32 PM"
"MyServer2","NA - DYNALG - SRV - Patching - Prod - Sat 18:00","Alive","4/16/2016 10:00:47 AM"
"YourServer","NA - All DA Servers - Patching - Prod - Fri 22:00","Alive","Access Denied!"
```

My current approach is shown below, the two `Where-Object` lines but that is getting cumbersome and its not easy to read.

I'm also not sure how I can update the static `"$((get-date).AddDays(7).ToString('MM-dd-yy')) 17:58"` into something dynamic which does the date/time calculation and the outputs the date/time string.  I've been able to use `[datetime]"04/23/2016 18:00" - (get-date)` but I'm just not sure how I can get the data into that format.

```
Where-Object {$_ -like '*sat?18:00*' -and $_.MaintenanceWindow -notmatch 'all.da.servers' -and $_.Server -match "^My"} | % {"{0}" -f $_.Server}

Where-Object {$_ -like '*sat?18:00*' -and $_.MaintenanceWindow -notmatch 'all.da.servers' -and $_.Server -match "^My"} | % {"{0}" -f $_.MaintenanceWindow -replace "^NA.+", "$((get-date).AddDays(7).ToString('MM-dd-yy')) 17:58"}
```

Comment: This probably is the best approach for filtering data.  You can improve readability by breaking the scriptblock up into multiple lines or putting it into a filter function.

Comment: To the downvote, would you care to post your objection(s) and offer suggestions for improvement?  Not everyone posting questions on this site is experienced with scripting/programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend upgrading your input CSV with additional fields, at least for the day and start time of the maintenance window, but perhaps also for the name of the server group. That would allow to greatly simplify filtering/processing.

If you need to dynamically calculate the date of next Saturday you can do it like this:

```
$today = [DateTime]::Today
$nextSaturday = $today.AddDays((7 - $today.AddDays(1).DayOfWeek))
```

Since you're using the same filter on both occasions you can combine the loops and do output via `Add-Content`. Still, wrapping the conditions as [@RyanBemrose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36669858/multiple-regular-expression-matching-in-powershell#comment60931918_36669858) suggested improves the overall readability of the filter. Also, using the formatting operator to put a string into an otherwise empty string is pointless, so remove that.

```
... | Where-Object {
  $_ -like '*sat?18:00*' -and
  $_.MaintenanceWindow -notmatch 'all.da.servers' -and
  $_.Server -match '^My'
} | ForEach-Object {
  $_.Server | Add-Content 'file1.txt'
  $_.MaintenanceWindow -replace '^NA.+', ('{0:MM-dd-yyy} 17:58' -f $nextSaturday) |
    Add-Content 'file2.txt'
}
```

Comment: I'm a little stuck on getting those two additional columns in the output CSV.  Question updated.

Comment: I think I got stuck in the [XY problem again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) but this time I'm aware of it.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer to the readability question.  Thanks again Ansgar Wiechers!  I am also going to put some time into creating a filter function to further clean up the script.